# Is the ServletContext same in jax-rs

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am designing two different restful api with
JAX-RS in Jetty. I have a question,is the same
ServletContext injected in my class?
Can my  two different services share the same object due to setAttribute in ServletContext?

Comment: That depends: Are they both in the same `.war` file? If yes then yes, if no then no. Each `.war` file is it's own servlet context. If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`ServletContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html), you'll find: *There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. (A "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed under a specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as `/catalog` and possibly installed via a `.war` file.)*

Comment: Sorry,I run it on osgi framework,and these is the same bundle

Comment: Thank you,I think I got the answer.
These two Rest API are in the same context path of my JAX-RS application,so they share the same servletContext

Answer (score 0):

There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. (A "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed under a specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as /catalog and possibly installed via a .war file.). Please check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)